# Occasionally incorrect position of a DIV in Firefox

Tags: html, css, jsp, http, firefox

I have an HTML page with the following layout:

[image]

The green square is a `<div>` which holds a data grid in the real application. The `<div>`
has an absolute position. Sometimes, Firefox displays the `<div>` in a wrong place (it has a correct position but in a wrong container):

[image]

On other occasions, the `<div>` appears in its proper place. I can reproduce this bug only in Firefox on both my Linux and Windows installations (no problem in Chrome, Opera and IE).
I also can only reproduce it when I access the page over the Internet (it cannot be reproduced when the application is deployed to the `localhost` web server).

The page is a JSP page and the problem appears most frequently when the server is busy and slow. When I save the page from the browser, and then open the file again, the green `<div>` moves back into its normal place. I think the problem has something to do with the timing of the HTTP response.

The page does not use JavaScript. It has a linked CSS file. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="b-panels">

    <!-- This is the left (blue) sidebar of the page. -->
    <div class="b-left-panel"></div>

    <!-- This is the center (white) area of the page. -->
    <div class="b-center-panel">

        <!-- This is the green <div>! -->
        <div class="dataGrid"> ... </div>

    </div>

    <!-- This is the right sidebar. It's not in the pictures. -->
    <div class="b-right-panel"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.b-panels {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.b-left-panel {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 190px;
}

.b-center-panel {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
}

.b-right-panel {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 140px;
}

/* This is the green <div>! */ 
.b-center-panel .dataGrid {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20;
    top: 20;
}
```

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I found a better solution. Wrapping the green `<div>` with one more `<div>` solved the problem:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <!-- This is the green <div>! -->
    <div class="dataGrid"> ... </div>

</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**OLD SOLUTION:**

I had to use JavaScript/jQuery to fix the problem. I used the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // if the browser is Firefox
    if (!(window.mozInnerScreenX == null)) {

        // get the position of the parent
        var panelLeftPos = $("#dataGrid").parent().position().left;

        // set the position of the green tag
        $("#dataGrid").css({top: 20, left: panelLeftPos + 20, position:'absolute'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

give the parent div of green div following css 
style="position:relative"

by giving this style your green div will take position relative to the parent div.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to solve it, but it did not work. I added `position: relative;` to my `.b-center-panel` CSS class, but the green `<div>` still appears in the wrong place on some occasions, and in its proper position in the rest of the cases.